# How to make a CheckBox list using <slot v-for> on VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-for

I must make a checkbox list based on a array in `data()`. But I'm having two problems.

**1.** I just can select the first checkbox, when I tap on the other checkboxes the only value changed is of first checkbox's list.

**2.** I can't get `@change` function, that not is triggered when I change checkbox's value.

```
<template>
...
<slot
  v-for="(termo, index) in termos"
  v-bind="termo"
  >
  <generic-check-box
    class="terms"
    input-id="termos[index].id"
    v-model="termos[index].term"
    :value="termos[index].term"
    @change="checkBoxChanged(index)"
    >
    <generic-text
      color="gray"
      class="condition"
    >{{ termos[index].message }}
    </generic-text>
  </generic-check-box>
</slot>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  components: {
    'close-button': CloseButton,
    'generic-button': GenericButton,
    'generic-check-box': GenericCheckBox,
    'generic-combo-box': GenericComboBox,
    'generic-title': GenericTitle,
    'generic-text': GenericText,
    'off-canvas-buttons': OffCanvasButtons
  },
  data () {
    return {
      termos: [
        { id: 0, term: true, message: 'Message 1' },
        { id: 1, term: false, message: 'Message 2' },
        { id: 2, term: false, message: 'Message 3' },
        { id: 3, term: false, message: 'Message 4' }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    checkBoxChanged (index) {
      console.log('checkBoxChangled: ' + index + ' ' + this.termos[index].term)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[image]

**EDIT**

[image]

Comment: Since it's custom checkbox, it would be great if you can provide the code of `<generic-check-box>` component. To get change event of the HTML `checkbox` (not the component) add `.native` modifier to `@change.native`.

Comment: The method is called now, it's works. The component is private and I can't share the code, but I could work if any way to work with a list of checkboxes

Comment: I see, what's the problem do you facing now?

Comment: I can't select the other checkboxes, just the first is selected. On the `checkBoxChanged` function I'm seeing: `checkBoxChangled: 0 true` or `checkBoxChangled: 0 false` when I tap on the any checkbox. Example: when I tap on the third checkbox, the first is selected.

Comment: `@change.native="termos[index].term = $event.target.checked"`

Comment: The `@change.native` works alright. The problem is that the correct index ins't passed. Apparentely the list think that all component is referencing to one (first)

Comment: have you tried my last comment out?

Comment: @Javas yes, I tried but not works. I edited the post with the behavior.

Comment: Hmm... without seeing the `<generic-check-box>` component's code, it's hard to say where is the problem is hidden.

Comment: When I try your code with a standard HTML checkbox it seems to update the correct checkbox. I suggest you try it too to confirm. Best guess is that there's a problem with your `generic-check-box` component.

Comment: @Javas @skirtle I added the `<generic-check-box>` source.

Comment: Did @skirtle answer help? It's definitely helped :)

Comment: @Javas yes, my problems are solved, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is this line:

```
input-id="termos[index].id"
```

It needs a `:` at the front:

```
:input-id="termos[index].id"
```

Otherwise `input-id` gets set to the string `'termos[index].id'` for all of your checkboxes. That string then gets used as the `id` for the inputs and the `for` of the labels. When clicking on any of the labels it will only trigger the first input with that `id`.

I would also note that your `generic-check-box` component doesn't appear to have a `value` prop defined. The other component is trying to use both `value` and `v-model` but these won't be passing in a value without a `value` prop.